# Google Sheets: Nasdaq: help with ranking on sub-population

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ooWW4YsnXN3JPH0Y71-FHiMIgC4kkNOjYuDYxDek5Vw/edit?usp=sharing

Can someone please help me with the formula in columns P,Q,R (highlighted in red)?
I need a formula which ranks in sub-populations:

column P:
Rank "spec/aandeel" &"Sector":
make a ranking per subpopulation of "spec/aandeel" and "sector".
There are 13 sectors (of which one blank) within 2 populations: "spec"="special, non share" and "aandeel"=common share.
To show what I try to obtain in a single dynamic formula in the dataset; is shown on the separate sheet "Pivot Table 1" with a pivot table and the RANK formula in column D.

Similar for column Q:
Rank within population of "spec/aandeel"&"Sector"&"Industry".

Similar for column R:
Rank "%Change" "Aandeel/speciaal".

It is so hard to do and I don't find good resources, but the one I applied.
Feel free to modify the file.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] On this site question content should not be removed when a solution is found, instead that solution should be posted as an answer or you might delete the question instead.